Set inputs of component in directive
I have a toolbar component which orchestrates which menu items should be displayed. The actions are defined in the template.
<teamx-action-template>
  <app-new-action />
  <app-open-action />
  <app-save-group>
    <app-save-action />
    <app-save-as-action />
  </app-save-group>
  <teamx-export-action />
</teamx-action-template>

Some of these actions are designed by another team and I do not want to pollute the scope of my component. Thats why I thought of a directive which handles filling inputs and reacting to outputs of the action (menu item) of Team X.
<teamx-export-action appExportActionAdapter />

Handling outputs is no problem with @HostBinding but how can I fill the @Input of ExportActionComponent of Team X? This component is listening to the changes via ngOnChanges and in my opinion setting the input directly and calling ngOnChanges is bad practice.
@Directive(...)
export class ExportActionAdapter implements OnInit {
  comp = inject(ExportActionComponent);
  businessExportService = inject(ExportService);

  ngOnInit() {
    const value = this.mapToViewModel(this.businessExportService.getExportMethods());
    this.comp.exports = value;
    this.comp.ngOnInit({
      ...
    });
  }

  mapToViewModel(...) {
    ...
  }
}

Which good solutions to fill the input and trigger ngOnChanges do you know?
